# How to add a symbolic link to bypass unavailable busybox applet

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I have BusyBox version v1.15.3 installed that came with the ROM gingerdx 31b. This busybox version cannot be updated/changed, because if it's being updated, the phone goes into a bootloop on the next reboot, it is said not to update the busybox in the ROM thread too.

The problem is, this busybox version doesn't include the applet `pgrep`. Whenever pgrep is typed in the shell & executed it gives out a `pgrep: not found` error. "pgrep" is needed by the "super charger" script to do some tasks.

So, I tried creating a symbolic link to a working pgrep from another busybox version. I stored the busybox file in the `/data/` folder, made it `chmod 777`, then `cd` to that directory. Then execute the command;

> ln -sf "busybox pgrep" "./busybox pgrep"

but even when I execute pgrep, it still gives the same error. How do I make the pgrep command point to a working pgrep, via another busybox or a pgrep file?

Also, how do I make this link permanent, so that it stays that way after a reboot? Should I add this to the .bashrc or do this using a init.d script? Both my knowledge on android & linux commands are limited as well. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking error. You've created a link named `busybox pgrep`, linking to a (not existing) other file of the same name. What you probably wanted to achieve is:

```
ln -sf </path/to/alternative/>busybox </path/to/linkdir/>pgrep
```

Replace `</path/to/alternative/>` with the path to the `busybox` binary featuring `pgrep` functionality, and `</path/to/linkdir/>` with the path to a directory contained in your `$PATH` (best the one where the other symlinks reside).

Busyboxes usually decide their "wanted functionality" by checking where they're called from. So the symlink is simply named `pgrep`, `grep`, or whatever, and pointing to the `busybox` binary.